# Flexbox doesn't stretch vertically in Firefox 52

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I try the following sketch (https://jsfiddle.net/m4njf8bL/):

```
<div style="position: relative; display: flex; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red; padding: 5px;">
  <button style="position: relative; display: flex; flex: 1 1 auto; flex-direction: column; align-items: stretch; justify-content: center; border: 1px solid green; ">
    <span style="display: flex; flex: 1 1 auto; align-items: stretch; justify-content: center; border: 1px solid blue;">Ololo</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

The inner span stretches vertically in all browsers except for Firefox. Why and is there a workaround?

Comment: Based on the info on http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox Firefox doesn't support that property on button elements, should be fixed on v.52 check https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984869#c2

Comment: I have Firefox 52 (in which it's supposed to be fixed), but it still doesn't stretch...

Comment: Yep I don't have that version but maybe check first if the flexbox works without the stretch maybe it's an extra bug, if that you could report it

Comment: Why do you need the span inside a button? You can either remove the span or put the button inside the span. Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: This is a simplified example. The real thing has something much more complex inside.